# Best method of storing data for android application?

Tags: php, android, mysql, database, sqlite

For my final year project, I decided to create an android app but unfortunately I have no experience with android development. Just a quick question which has confused me for the last few weeks, and I was hoping someone here could give me some advice and guidance.

I'm wanting to create a kind of student (university) guide to the UK, allowing the user to browse through bars and clubs suggested by other students.

For the purpose of the project, the data contained on the database will be about bars and clubs in my area which have been chosen by myself. If everything goes well I hope to publish the app to the android market, I would then produce a website where students could contribute their suggests and rate existing.

I'm slightly unsure of the best way to store the data. Whether using internal storage (SQLite) or server based using MySQL and PHP. As I'm currently still at the design stage of the process, I have no idea of the size of the data or database.

The database will store a variety of information

- Venue details (general info,contact details,website, Facebook page)
- Google maps (gps location data on venues - longitude and latitude i think)
- Drink prices (price of cheapest lager and cider for every venue, eg strongbow £2.60)
- Student offers (drink or ticket offers such as double vodka £2 or £3 entry with NUS card)
- Student nights (info on the event such as name,theme,entry,entry time, music and possibly a small description at the bottom of around 500/600 characters)

The drink offers will be linked to the student nights rather than been a separate element, whilst on the night profile by clicking a tab or sliding the screen to the left will show you the drink offer relevant to that night

Example of a possible description on student night page

*Faces is the new Monday night the town has been talking about. Launched in November Faces offers a different clubbing experience to most other club nights out there. With resident djs from Koosday Newcastle and a hand picked selection of male and female hosts, Faces is really a cut above. Each Monday we operate 4 rooms with music spanning across all genre's complete with a brand new VIP room. Drinks from 99p and a new cocktail menu to get your mouth watering. Full club decor has been installed along with a re jig in each room to make Faces the ultimate club night.*

Any information or advice would be much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: sqlite local database. see SqliteOpenHelper. Databases can hold millions of entrys and I think just your area would be find on a local db, if you did more than your area, then think webservice.

Answer (score 3):

I would actually go for something along the lines of MySQL and PHP. An sqlite database would be difficult to manage with user contributions.

Set up an php based api and have your applications talk to it using json encoded requests. That way all users have access to the same database. It would require internet access, but would help avoid synchronization problems when a user contributes data.

Comment: The user will only have read only access to the database via the app, I was just hoping to provide a web interface for users to suggest locations but at a later date.

Answer (score 1):

Since you anticipate users populating the data overtime via a web interface, you'll need to store the data in the network using your favorite database and web application framework.  MySQL and PHP should work fine.

You may still want to use the SqlLite database on the device for caching purposes.

Comment: Yeah I hope users will populate overtime but for the purpose of the project i will be populating just for some mock data. Is using a SQLite database for caching the best method to go about this? Thanks for replying

Comment: Seems SQLite would be appropriate for mocking up data as you describe above.  You might also want to consider using preferences or local files.